# Posting to Facebook wall

Tags: python, facebook

This has been asked several times, but after reading many different posts I still have not a basic version running for posting to a wall.

I want to post to a wall of a FB user with python. The PHP SDK (https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk) uses this as the first example. I need the equivalent code in python.

```
require 'facebook-php-sdk/src/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'YOUR_APP_ID',
  'secret' => 'YOUR_APP_SECRET',
));

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();
```

The pythonsdk (https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk) says the basic usage is:

```
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(oauth_access_token)
```

Without explaining what that the oauth_access_token is.

According to here: [Python - Facebook API - Need a working example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11510850/python-facebook-api-need-a-working-example) one has to generate an access token?

Answer (score 5):

An access token is used to authorize your application to do stuff on the users behalf. There are several ways (also referred to as "flows") to get such a token, you can read up on it here: [Facebook Developers Access Tokens](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/). Facebook provides a tool for generating test tokens, you can find it here: [Facebook Developers Access Token Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token/).

Install **facebook** module by running the below command (if it isn't installed).

```
  pip install facebook-sdk
```

Generate a token and run this code to post on your wall:

```
import facebook

ACCESS_TOKEN = "<your access token>"; # do not forget to add access token here
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(ACCESS_TOKEN)
graph.put_object("me", "feed", message="Hello, World!")
```

Comment: Thanks. Using your solution I get: "facebook.GraphAPIError: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user." I have arrived at something similar, but using a PROFILE_ID. With this I get: ""(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action"

Comment: Run your access token through the debugger: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/access_token